# Apache Kafka Streams : Out-of-Order messages

Tags: apache-kafka, timestamp, extractor

I have an Apache Kafka 2.6 Producer which writes to topic-A (TA).
I also have a Kafka streams application which consumes from TA and writes to topic-B (TB).
In the streams application, I have a custom timestamp extractor which extracts the timestamp from the message payload.

For one of my failure handling test cases, I shutdown the Kafka cluster while my applications are running.

When the producer application tries to write messages to TA, it cannot because the cluster is down and hence (I assume) buffers the messages.
Let's say it receives 4 messages m1,m2,m3,m4 in increasing time order. (i.e. m1 is first and m4 is last).

When I bring the Kafka cluster back online, the producer sends the buffered messages to the topic, but they are not in order. I receive for example, m2 then m3 then m1 and then m4.

Why is that ? Is it because the buffering in the producer is multi-threaded with each producing to the topic at the same time ?

I assumed that the custom timestamp extractor would help in ordering messages when consuming them. But they do not. Or maybe my understanding of the timestamp extractor is wrong.

I got one solution from SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46708290/kafka-streams-how-to-change-a-records-timestamp-0-11-0?rq=1), to just stream all events from tA to another intermediate topic (say tA') which will use the TimeStamp extractor to another topic. But I am not sure if this will cause the events to get reordered based on the extracted timestamp.

My code for the Producer is as shown below (I am using Spring Cloud for creating the Producer):
**Producer.java**

```java
@Service
public class Producer {

    private String topicName = "input-topic";
        
    private ApplicationProperties appProps;
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, MyEvent> kafkaTemplate;
    
    public Producer() {
        super();        
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void setAppProps(ApplicationProperties appProps) {
        this.appProps = appProps;
        this.topicName = appProps.getInput().getTopicName();
    }

    public void sendMessage(String key, MyEvent ce) {
        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String,MyEvent>> future = this.kafkaTemplate.send(this.topicName, key, ce); 
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is that ? Is it because the buffering in the producer is multi-threaded with each producing to the topic at the same time ?

By default, the producer allow for up to 5 parallel in-flight requests to a broker, and thus if some requests fail and are retried the request order might change.

To avoid this re-ordering issue, you can either set `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 1` (what may have a performance hit) or set `enable.idempotence = true`.

Btw: you did not say if your topic has a single partition or multiple partitions, and if your messages have a key? If your topic has more then one partition and you messages are sent to different partitions, there is no ordering guarantee on read anyway, because offset ordering is only guaranteed within a partition.

> I assumed that the custom timestamp extractor would help in ordering messages when consuming them. But they do not. Or maybe my understanding of the timestamp extractor is wrong.

The timestamp extractor only extracts a timestamp. Kafka Streams does not re-order any messages, but processes messages always in offset-order.

> If not, then what are the specific uses of the timestamp extractor ? Just to associate a timestamp with an event ?

Correct.

> I got one solution from SO here, to just stream all events from tA to another intermediate topic (say tA') which will use the TimeStamp extractor to another topic. But I am not sure if this will cause the events to get reordered based on the extracted timestamp.

No, it won't do any reordering. The other SO question is just about to change the timestamp, but if you read messages in order a,b,c the result would be written in order a,b,c (just with different timestamps, but offset order should be preserved).

This talk explains some more details: https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-san-francisco-2019/whats-the-time-and-why/

Comment: To your question about whether or not we use keys, yes we do.
I tried with max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1 and the ordering is preserved during retries.

So, will ```enable.idempotence=true``` also incur a performance hit, while maintaining ordering of messages ?

Comment: `enable.idempotence=true` might also have a perf hit, but it might be smaller than `max.in.flight.request.per.connection=1` -- also, if you enable idempotent writes, you also guard agains duplicates in case of retries (otherwise, a retry could result in duplicates appends to the topic, because a write might have been successful, but only the ack is lost triggering the retry).

Comment: Also, my topic has 2 partitions. If my messages have keys, then why does Kafka not maintain ordering (even if they are being retried) ? I thought  one of the benefits of having message keys was to ensure that they all end up in the same partition and also get ordered within that partition. Are there any reference docs which can show me how the retry mechanism works ?

Comment: If your message have the same key, you are good. But in your question you did not say anything about key, so it was unclear if they may have a key at all or may have different or the same key.

Comment: `Are there any reference docs which can show me how the retry mechanism works?` -- Not really, but it's simple: the producer buffers records in batches and sends a write request per batch. Thus the original write requests are send in-order. However, if an error occurs, it those send request and enqueued into the send FIFO queue again at the end and thus could violate the order afterwards: send(1), send(2), send(3) -- send(1) fails, and is re-enqueued at the end. Not the send order (if there is no more failures) is 2 / 3 / 1.

Comment: Thanks @Mathias J. Sax

Comment: Your explanation is very intuitive.
I use keys, but still the retried messages are out-of-order. So not sure why that is the case. 
In my case, if I set ```max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1```, what changes w.r.t. send(1), send(2), send(3). Does it mean that the producer will keep trying 1 till it is successful. And ONLY then try 2 and finally 3. Which is why ordering is preserved in this case ?

Comment: Correct. With `max.in.flight=1` the request queue length is set to 1 and thus `send(1)` is retried until successful before send(2) gets enqueued.

Comment: I have enabled idempotence to true but even then the messages are produced out of sequence in some cases and in-sequence in some cases. Not sure why it is so inconsistent behaviour. What can I do to get a clue to this issue ? (BTW I am using message keys, so all messages have the same key yet messages are not in sequence when the issue occurs)

Comment: Hard to say -- if only the broker goes down but the consumer stays up, re-ordering should not occur. What's your topic config though: replication factor should be 3, and min-in-sync-replicas should be 2. -- Can you reproduced the issue also without idempotent writes, but `max.in.flight=1`?

Comment: @Mathias J. Sax
I see that the min.insync.replicas is the default of 1. I will also try by setting it to 2. Our topic replication factor is 3.
I will try with max.in.flight = 1 as well. (and change idempotence to false)

Comment: I changed min.insync.replicas to 2 and this throws up the following error after the producer (re)tries to publish the message after the Kafka cluster is started.
NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS

Comment: During startup, this can happen: if only one broker is online, it cannot accept the write yet. The producer should retry internally though but should not fail (if configures correctly).

Comment: I checked that the internal topics such as __consumer_offsets and transaction-state topics were configured with a default replication factor of 1 and hence the above error of NOT_ENOUGH_REPLICAS. I changed the internal topic replication factor to 3 and now there are no such errors. 
I will now try with this config and see if there are any ordering issues for my failure scenario.

Question : Why does min-insync-replicas need to be more than 1 so as to achieve idempotency ? doesn't the broker automatically set this value to say 1 less than replication factor when we enable idempotency ?

Comment: In general, to make sure you have a fault-tolerant config, you need to set min-insync to larger than one -- otherwise, there is no guarantee and you could still lose data. -- The sequence numbers that idempotent producer is using are store in the topics and thus if you lose data and sequence numbers, idempotent writes cannot be guaranteed. -- And no, the broker won't reconfigures topic. It's your responsibility to configure topics correctly.

Comment: I tried with both configurations, but the producer still publishes messages out of sequence. I have tried this even with a single broker cluster with just 1 partition and replica per topic.
All I am doing is using ```producer.send``` to send the request asynchronously. Not sure why this happens. I don't care about what result I get from the async send (this is just a test code). I have updated the question with my sample code.

Comment: I am running out of ideas. Maybe worth to file a bug report.

Comment: Raised KAFKA-12776 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-12776?filter=-2)

Comment: In addition, why does the KafkaProducer.send blocks for max.block.ms when the cluster is unavailable ? I presumed it was an async call which will return immediately.

Comment: In general it will return immediately: Internally, the producer has a fixed size buffer to store the records and `send()` will put the records into this buffer and can return afterwards (the actual send happens when a background thread takes the record out of this buffer). If the brokers are not available, this buffer will fill up though, and when calling `send()` the new record cannot be put into the buffer because it's full and thus the `send()` call blocks for this case.